# Need to change colors on the Pivot Chart using VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Problem:

I am generating reports using Excel 2010, and multiple pivot charts. When I generate reports I can not set the colors of the pivot chart series to a static value. Some times "Pass" series displayed as "RED" and this creates confusion.

I try to use the code below to force to change the colors on the series:

```
Sheets("PSD").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 5").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
```

The problem with the code is that **SeriesCollection(1)** is not always the same series I want and when I update the code as SeriesCollection("Pass"), it does NOT work.

I need to find a way to refer the **SeriesCollection** by name, and if it does NOT there I can continue using **On Error Resume Next** no need to check it.

Answer (score 3):

To get a handle on a series by it's name you can do this:

```
Sub cht()
    Dim cht As Chart
    Set cht = Sheets("PSD").ChartObjects("Chart 5").Chart

    Dim ss As Series
    Set ss = cht.SeriesCollection("Pass")

    With ss.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Sorry to ask, but I am not a programmer and was little confused with the code above, your code does not define which chart is selected. "ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 5").Activate", since I have about 9 charts how would you define which chart is selected?

Comment: In addition I do get a Run time error '91' when I run the code. "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: Okay, see my update.  I fully defined the chart and sheet and removed `ActiveChart`.  The previous code required you to select a chart first and then run the macro.  There is still no error handling so make sure your chart, sheet and series names are correct.  My example attempts to match the info you provided.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad it worked.  I noticed that you haven't marked any of your questions as answered.  If you have satisfactory answers provided please take the time to mark them as answered so that they are not left open.  Here is a link to more info if you have questions [answer].  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was just working on this.

you can evaluate the name of the indexed seriescollection and then act according to it. here is my example for 8 (hard coded) situations that I have on my possibilities of series, but i guess it can be dynamic somehow.

```
 Sub Format_GraphPertes_TRG(PV_Chart_Name)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim i
    
    
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(PV_Chart_Name).Activate

    
'== Balayage des legendes dans le chart
For i = 1 To 8
    
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Select
    'MsgBox ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Name
    
    Select Case Left(ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Name, 2)
    
    Case "01"        
        With Selection.Format.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
            .Transparency = 0
            .Solid
        End With
     
    Case "02"
        With Selection.Format.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            .Transparency = 0
            .Solid
        End With
        
    Case "03"
        With Selection.Format.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            .Transparency = 0
            .Solid
        End With
        
    Case "04"
        With Selection.Format.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(174, 171, 171)
            .Transparency = 0
            .Solid
        End With
   
        
    Case "05"
        With Selection.Format.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(72, 161, 250)
            .Transparency = 0
            .Solid
        End With
    
         
    Case "06"
        With Selection.Format.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(201, 43, 152)
            .Transparency = 0
            .Solid
        End With
    
        
    Case "07"
        With Selection.Format.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(47, 103, 153)
            .Transparency = 0
            .Solid
        End With
        
    End Select
    
    
Next

    
    
End Sub
```