# Accessing PivotChart SeriesCollection with a Sub

Tags: excel, vba

I am quite new to VBA. I have written a macro which creates about 10 pivot charts and some normal charts after filtering and cutting some data from a database spreadsheet. I now want to write a sub which goes through applying the same formatting to each one. The sub is as follows:

```
Sub FormatChart(Cht As ChartObject, title As String)
Cht.Activate
MsgBox ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count
With ActiveChart
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = title
     .Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = False
End With
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 182, 0)
End With
End Sub
```

I originally didn't include all the activates and selects, but couldn't get the macro to work without them and don't see it as the end of the world - the datasets are never going to be massive so speed isn't so much of a concern, and I disable screenupdating so that users can't click on cells/other objects and disrupt the macro as it runs.

Here's my problem. If I take out the second With loop, everything proceeds perfectly and the gridlines are removed and the title is added. However, whenever I try to edit the colours of columns with the above I get Run time error '1004': Invalid parameter. I've also tried keeping the content of the second with loop inside the first but then moved it out to try using selection to see if it made a difference.

I've fiddled around quite a bit and recorded various macros changing the colour of the chart in question, but I think the problem might be to do with referencing SeriesCollection as when I try to debug with

```
MsgBox ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count
```

I get "0".

Please let me know if I'm missing the point - as I said I am new to VBA and am trying to learn as much as possible :)

EDIT: The solution was that I was passing each chart to the above sub after I had created the chart, but before I had set a data source for the chart. Doh!

This obviously meant that there were no seriesCollections for that chart, hence the error I was getting.

I marked Joehannah as answering the question (even though it isn't technically the solution) because it made me check my code and notice that the above could be causing the problem - if I shouldn't do that someone please tell me and I'll try to fix it!

Comment: Try this `.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB` [Also check this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27027264/1389394)

Comment: Hi bonCodigo, unfortunately all my charts are bar charts rather than line charts. I had looked at that answer previously, and do not want to reference any named series as I am using the sub to refer to multiple charts. Having said that I tried to reference a named series just to see if it would work, with 'ActiveChart.SeriesCollection("Total"). It still didn't work :(

Comment: The above link has the exact info you were looking for, that's why it was given. The answer below just has the same info. By setting the chart object into a reference variable, is the way to go about it. Each chart has a name too, not necessarily a name given by you, but `chart1`, `chart2`. To keep things clean, why don't you give a name when the objects are created?

Comment: The link above deals with taking a specific chart for which you know the series names (in that example, the OP has a chart with a series "Pass") and formatting those series. My example is creating a subroutine where you pass in a chart and a title as arguments and then format the chart regardless of series name. I name each chart as I create it, and pass it just after it has been created into the sub above. Neither the link above nor Joehanna's answer specifically answered my problem, which was that I passed the chart to my sub before I had assigned a data source. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: There are no obligations to provide answers or helpful comments. Welcome to Stackoverflow! Passing a chart as a parameter or you set it to a chart reference object, it's the same. At the end you have a chart reference object which you are able to use by `with` or by the ref object itself. The point is why can't you use `Set theseries = Cht.SeriesCollection(1)` ? If an answer doens't answer, there's no obligation to accept it. Someone else may answer correctly or you may even answer it yourself.

Comment: Thanks you! You are totally right, you can reference the seriescollection either way. As I said in the edit to my question, I just noticed my mistake, which was actually kind of unrelated to my original question since the code above was fine, it was where I was calling it that was the problem. Your suggestion would also work if I put it into the sub above :D

Comment: [Post your answer, so someone else may benefit from it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been told to post my own answer since I figured out the issue.

I was passing each chart to this function just after creating it, as follows:

```
Set ptr1 = Sheets("withinBRSPivots").PivotTables("UniqueClicks").TableRange1
Set cht1 = Sheets("BRS Overview").ChartObjects.Add(Left:=950, Top:=500, _
    Width:=400, Height:=300)
cht1.Name = "UCChart"
Charter.FormatChart cht1, "Average Number of Unqique Clicks"
```

I then set the source data for the chart after doing the above. This meant that when the chart was passed to my chartformat sub, it had no source data. This is what resulted in being able to edit the title and gridlines, but not the seriesCollection. The fix was to just move the FormatChart sub line to after I had set the source data.

Many thanks to everyone who posted answers!

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using `Set cht = (create chart object)` for each chart and then Immediately calling the format method passing in `cht`.

Comment: Hi Joehanna, I would prefer not to have to add the formatting code in for every chart as it will be literally identical and would prefer to just use a sub to keep my code as short and neat as possible (the main sub is already about 800 lines long). Is there any reason in particular that it can't be done by passing the chart as an argument to a sub?

Comment: I didn't say put the code in-line. Keep it as a separate method. Just call the format method immediately afte you create each chart.

Comment: So, I was about to say that's exactly what I'm doing at the moment, when I checked my code and realised what the source of the problem is :D. I was calling my chartformat sub after I had created the chart but before I set any source data. Obviously, this means that stuff like hasTitle worked, but since there was no data in the chart, there were no seriescollections. I'm a fool! I moved the chartformat to after I had set the source data and all was fixed. Thank you so much for the hint! :)

Comment: @joehanna how does your answer differ from the link given in my commenet above?